# Why would Flashbuilder 4 work in Internet Explorer but not in Firefox?

Tags: flash, cross-browser, flexbuilder, flashbuilder4

When I produce an application in Flashbuilder 4 and click the green run button, it opens Firefox with this URI:

```
file:///C:/chapter_1/starter/Getting_Started/PersonalTrainerWebApp_Finished/bin-debug/Main.html
```

but the screen is blank (grey, right-click says "about adobe flash player 10")

but if I copy that URI into Explorer, it is converted to:

```
C:\aaaPersonalTrainerWebApp_Finished\bin-debug\Main.html
```

and it works fine. If I copy this URI back into firefox, it converts back to the old one and is blank.

**How can I get the Flash application to run in Firefox as well?**

Comment: maybe you haven't installed the flash plugin on firefox as well,note that IE installs an ActiveX control for flash,while other browsers use a plugin

Comment: thanks but when I go to http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about, firefox and the other non-IE browsers (chrome, opera) all say that they have "version 10,1,82,76 installed". it must have something to do with explorer being able to convert the URI. I've tried running Firefox in "Work Offline" mode but no change.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, that happens to me and I almost got crazy about it, then I realize that it wouldn't run in something like "local" mode, so I move it to my web server and it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

try to run your url on a webserver, and install the debug version of flash player to check error with http://www.sephiroth.it/firefox/flashtracer/ for example.